# "This comment is not eligible for flagging" is eligible for flagging

Tags: bug

I tried to upvote a comment on a historical post, and received this message:

[image]

But when I try to flag it:

[image]

It goes through, and thanks me for flagging it.

Is this a bug? Shouldn't we display the first box if one attempts to flag a comment? Or remove the flag statement from it?

Comment: I'm guessing something is getting confused by the fact that the question is locked, thus preventing voting on the question and answers, but the comments on the answers to a locked question can still be flagged.

Comment: Just remove "or flagging" from the text.  Should only take 6-8 weeks to fix.